# Declare an array formatting

Tags: java

I have the code for making a array of 8 random digits between 50-100 but I can not figure out how to get my even and odds counter working and where how to add the array of 8 numbers up for a total. Can someone help me please?

The Problem:

Declare an array to hold eight integers. Use a for loop to add eight random integers, all in the range from 50 to 100, inclusive, to this array. Duplicates are okay. Next, pass the array to a method that sorts the array and returns another array containing only the largest and smallest elements in the original array. Print these two values in main. Then use a foreach loop to display all elements of the sorted array on one line separated by a single space. This latter loop should also count the odd and even numbers in the array and determine the sum of all elements in the array.

My Code so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Assignment1 {
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] randomEight = numbers();
        int[] smallestLargest =  sortArrayAndReturnSmallestLargest(randomEight);
        System.out.println("Here is the Lowest number ");
        System.out.println((smallestLargest[0]));
        System.out.println("Here is the Largest number ");
        System.out.println((smallestLargest[1]));
        System.out.println("Here is the array");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomEight)); 


        System.out.println();
    }
    public static int[] numbers(){
        int evenCount = 0;
        int oddCount = 0;
        int[] randomEight =  new int[8];
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
            randomEight [x] = rand.nextInt((100 - 50) + 1) + 50;
        for(int item: randomEight){
            if(item % 2 == 0){
               evenCount++;
           } else {
               oddCount++;
           }
        }
        }
        System.out.println("Here is the Evens: ");
        System.out.println(evenCount);
        System.out.println("Here is the Odds");
        System.out.println(oddCount);
        return randomEight;


    }

    public static int[] sortArrayAndReturnSmallestLargest(int[] randomEight){
        int[] smallestLargest = new int[2];
        Arrays.sort(randomEight);
        smallestLargest[0] = randomEight[0];
        smallestLargest[1] = randomEight[7];
        return smallestLargest;
    }


}
```

My Output:

```
Here is the Evens: 
53
Here is the Odds
11
Here is the Lowest number 
53
Here is the Largest number 
96
Here is the array
[53, 54, 57, 58, 62, 75, 80, 96]
```

Sample Output:

```
 The lowest element is 59
 The highest element is 96
 Here is the array
 59 64 76 77 80 88 91 96 
 Evens: 5, odds: 3
 Total: 631
```

Comment: So what is your exact problem? you dunno how to pass argument to a method? You dunno how to pass an array as an argument to a method? You dunno how to declare method with parameter? You dunno how to sort?

Comment: You will just need to implement some kind of sorting function. How you want to do that is up to you, but I personally like [bubble sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: You are already importing java.util.Arrays in your project.  This contains a sort method.

Comment: Im not good with all of the things Adrian Shum mentioned

Comment: You are using x as a varibale in the loop for finding even-odd....use item

Comment: if(**item** % 2 == 0){
               evenCount++;
           } else {
               oddCount++;
           }
        }

Comment: One more suggestion....it would be good if you will take that even/odd logic out of here...this will make program more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do the second portion of the problem you could do:

```
private int[] sortArrayAndReturnSmallestLargest(int[] randomArray){
    int[] smallestLargest = new int[2];
    Arrays.sort(randomArray);
    smallestLargest[0] = randomArray[0];
    smallestLargets[1] = randomArray[randomArray.size()-1];
    return smallestLargest
}
```

To use the above from the main method:

```
int[] smallestLargest = sortArrayAndReturnSmallestLargest(randomEight)
```

I don't want to complete your entire homework assignment for you.  My intention is to show you how to do some things that are not yet comfortable for you.  Per the instructions you should be able to use the loop below to count, sum and print most of what you need to do.

In order to get a count of evens and odds you'll want to create counters, loop the randomArray and increment the count of each depending on whether or not the int value is even or odd.  You could do something like the following:

```
int evenCount = 0;
int oddCount = 0;

for(int item: randomEight){
   //Use modulo to determine even vs odd
   if(item % 2 == 0){
       evenCount++;
   } else {
       oddCount++;
   }
}
```

Here's complete code.  I wrote this is a text file so I'm not promising anything.  As you can see I took the assignment and broke each sentence down into a comment so you can see how you need to look at these things.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Assignment1 {

public static void main(String[] args){

private static Random rand = new Random();
int evenCount = 0;
int oddCount = 0;
int sum = 0;

//Declare an array to hold eight integers. 
int[] arrayWithEightInts = new int[8];

//Use a for loop to add eight random integers, all in the range from 50 to 100, inclusive, to this array. Duplicates are okay.

for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
        arrayWithEightInts [x] = rand.nextInt((100 - 50) + 1) + 50;
}

//Next, pass the array to a method that sorts the array and returns another array containing only the largest and smallest elements in the original array. 
int[] smallestLargest = sortArrayAndReturnSmallestLargest(arrayWithEightInts);

//Print these two values in main. 
System.out.println(“The lowest element is ” + smallestLargest[0];
System.out.println(“The highest element is ” + smallestLargest[1];

//Then use a foreach loop to display all elements of the sorted array on one line separated by a single space. This latter loop should also count the odd and even numbers in the array and determine the sum of all elements in the array.
System.out.println(“Here is the array”);
for(int item: arrayWithEightInts){
    sum = sum + item;
    System.out.print(item + “ ”);
    if(x % 2 == 0){
                evenCount++;
    } else {
                oddCount++;
    }
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println(“Evens: ” + evenCount + “, odds: “ + oddCount);
System.out.println(“Total: ” + sum);
}


public static int[] sortArrayAndReturnSmallestLargest(int[] randomEight){
    int[] smallestLargest = new int[2];
    Arrays.sort(randomEight);
    smallestLargest[0] = randomEight[0];
    smallestLargest[1] = randomEight[randomEight.size()-1];
    return smallestLargest;
}
}
```

Comment: How do I pass my array of 8 random digits to your first array and what would I put to print it out in main

Comment: Your teacher's goal here is to make you understand that in Java, for the most part, objects are passed by reference.  So when the randomArray is sorted in the other method you do not need to pass it back to the main method.  It now points to the sorted array.  I imagine your professor would also prefer you to create/use/copy a sorting algorithm by yourself rather than use Arrays.sort....

Comment: I understand but in my class I am my own teacher and I have to learn by examples and help on here.

Comment: Thank you so much for those note on each step

Answer (score 0):

> I can not figure out how to pass the array and sort it for all the
>   different ways the problem asks

you dont need to sort the array to get the answer to those questions, just use custom made methods.

***The lowest element: *** do a loop in the array and use a variable to set the lowest value..

***The highest element: *** same as the method before

***Here is the array: *** I think you are done with that

***Evens and odds: *** loop the array and check x%2==0 or x%2!=0 
(hint: you need to do only one of those methods.... remember ***evens+odds = arrays.size***)

***Total: *** loop the array and use a variable to accumulate the result

Answer (score 0):

Michel, Its so difficult to keep track of the changes as you are updating the same question every time. Please take a step back and dry run your code before simply running it. The issue here is in your for Loop:

```
Line1:for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
               Line2: randomEight [x] = rand.nextInt((100 - 50) + 1) + 50;
               Line3:  for(int item: randomEight){
               Line4:     if(item % 2 == 0){
               Line5:        evenCount++;
               Line6:    } else {
               Line7:        oddCount++;
               Line8:    }
               Line9: }
               Line10:  }
```

For the code above it goes like this.

- The outerLoop starts at Line1 and initializes x as 0
- At Line2 you assing a random number to array assume 79.
- At Line3 you start another loop which again iterates over the entire array and checks for the even/odds..

Understand here that your loops runs for n*n times but it is not supposed to do that. You only have to check the number which is now inserted into the array.

Please change your code as below. Hope this helps

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
            randomEight [x] = rand.nextInt((100 - 50) + 1) + 50;
            if(isPrime(randomEight [x])){
                evenCount++;
            }else{
                oddCount++;
            }
        }
private static boolean isPrime(int item){
        boolean flag = false;

        if(item % 2 == 0){
            flag =  true;
        } else {
            flag =  false;
        }

        return flag;
    }
```